# How to join two tables into a dictionary in dbt jinja

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, jinja2, dbt

I want to create a for loop in dbt that loops through two columns of a table in my database and created case when statements using the values in each row of the two columns. Just like this:

```
{% set locations = {'%United-States%':'United States', '%USA%':'United States'} %}

select
    case
        {% for feeder, correct in locations.items() %}
            when lower(locationname) like {{feeder}} then {{correct}}
        {% endfor %}
    end as city
from table
```

I was able to create lists for both feeder and correct, but I am not able to merge them as key-value pairs of a dictionary to loop through it. Any ideas on how should I do this?

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure if I'm understanding the problem, I just compiled that code and it works fine, it shows `when lower(locationname) like %United-States% then United States`. The only thing that I'm missing is some quotes around `"{{correct}}"` if that is supposed to be a String. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey Javier, thanks for your answer, the code I wrote works fine, but instead of manually writing the values in the dictionary, I want them to be the rows of a table that has two columns and live in my database, so I want them to be dynamically coded into the for loop.

Comment: you're basically asking for python's `zip()` function to join two lists into a dict, right?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you have two problems:

1. fetch data from another table, and
2. use that data to populate a case when statement.

Big thing to remember is that the main thing that dbt-jinja does is create a string of SQL. That said, there is clever functionality that lets you query a database *before* jinja starts to put the string together.

The idea being:

1. fetch the values from the database that you want to have included in your SELECT query
2. populate the previously fetched values into the query while rendering the statement

there's two macros that may be of use in the first step:

- `run_query()` ([docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query)), and
- dbt-utils' `get_query_results_as_dict()` ([docs](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_query_results_as_dict-source))

Something like this might work (provided you already have dbt-utils installed:

```sql
{% set locations_query %}
select feeder, correct from my_other_table
{% endset %}
{% set locations = run_query(locations_query) %}

select
    case
        -- not sure how this part will work yet....
        {% for feeder, correct in locations.items() %}
            when lower(locationname) like {{feeder}} then {{correct}}
        {% endfor %}
    end as city
from table
```

Comment: The above worked almost perfectly but didn't even need the `.items()` modifier. Final looked like: `{% for key, clean_key in key_dict %}`